# Spring RestTemplate throws 404 but curl and browser call works

Tags: spring, curl, resttemplate

RestTemplate Code :

```
    final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);      

    ResponseEntity<String> quote = restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://localhost:8080/groups/HOLDEN_REGION",HttpMethod.GET, entity , String.class);
```

Controller Code :

@RestController
public class GroupController {

```
@RequestMapping(value="/groups/{groupTypeName}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public Set<Group> getGroups(@ApiParam(value = "groupTypeName", required = true) @PathVariable("groupTypeName") String groupTypeName) {
    return groupService.getGroupsForGroupTypeName(groupTypeName);
}

}
```

When i hit the same url using curl and browser , its working with no issues. But when i use spring resttemplate, i am getting 404 error . I have tried to set the headers and all, but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What headers are you using?
And have you tried other RestTemplate methods like getForObject or getForEntity?

Comment: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Authorization: Basic ********=
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Try building your way up with the headers, one by one, could be that one of them is giving you issues. Also, for GET requests, try a simpler getForObject that is pretty straightforward and easy to use